# Passing Additional Arguments with map() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, arguments, prop

I'm currently mapping over a prop like so:

```
  renderList(item) {
      return(
        </div>
          shows up
        </div>
    )
  }

  render() { 
    return(
        <div> 
          {this.props.items.map(this.renderList)}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have another prop I would like to pass

```
this.props.completed
```

A simplified version of what I would like to do

```
  renderList(item, completed) {
      return(
        </div>
          shows up
        </div>
    )
  }

  render() { 
    return(
        <div> 
          {this.props.items.map(this.renderList(this.props.items, this.props.completed)}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to pass another prop with this map function?

Comment: Can you give more context of what you are trying to do, its not clear for me. Can you add more code?

Comment: @AhmedHawas I added a bit more code hope it makes sense

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are (at least) 3 ways to go about this. The simplest is to bind `renderList` to your component instance and reference `this.props.completed` within it:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    // it's more efficient to bind your functions once in the constructor than
    // doing so on every render
    this.renderList = this.renderList.bind(this);
  }

  renderList(item) {
      const completed = this.props.completed;
      return(
        <div>
          shows up
        </div>
    )
  }

  render() { 
    return(
        <div> 
          {this.props.items.map(this.renderList)}
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Another option is to use a closure to pass the property into the function:

```
  renderList(completed, item) {
      return(
        <div>
          shows up
        </div>
    )
  }

  render() { 
    const completed = this.props.completed;
    const renderList = this.renderList;
    return(
        <div> 
          {this.props.items.map(function (item) {
             return renderList(completed, item);
          })}
        </div>
    );
  }
```

A third option would be to bind the property to the `map()` callback.

```
  renderList(completed, item) {
      return(
        <div>
          shows up
        </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <div> 
          {this.props.items.map(this.renderList.bind(this, this.props.completed))}
        </div>
    );
  }
```